# CMD: FINDSTR: Cannot open Filename

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I got this very wierd and unexplainable issue that boggles my mind for quite some time. Each time I run into this issue and I cannot figure out what is wrong since it is the same as it is for the other variables.

I know that there is probably some forum page wedged between the thousands of pages related to this where I could find my answer, however I cannot find that one in a thousand page.

So I am working on a script to run a filter for lines through and it is working fine except for this one stupid and stubbern variable that gives me the error message.

So when I run the following from my Bat-File called Test.bat (to keep names short) it gives me the error message following after.

Code:

```
@ECHO off
    set CNAME="RefilterMe"
    SET SPT="C:\ICT\RefilterMe.txt"
    SET SPT2="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.ReFiltered.txt"
    SET SPT3="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp.txt"
    SET SPT4="C:\ICT\Refiltered"
    SET SPT5="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"
    SET SPT6="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp2Test.txt"
    SET SPT7="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Filtered.Temp.txt"

TYPE %SPT% > %SPT5%
```

Error:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Programms.txt"
```

While writing my question I of course realized that it says 'C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Proper.txt"' instead of 'C:\ICT\RefilterMe.Programms.txt'.
The part of 'TYPE %SPT% > %SPT5%' is placed directly behind the variable zone / area and it's so odd that it only happens to this one line.

Here some analysis info.

Test:

Copied SPT6 and named it SPT8. This one ran through no issue. But when I changed it to SPT5 and SPT5 to SPT8 it was also shifting with the issue.

```
@ECHO off
    set CNAME="RefilterMe"
    SET SPT="C:\ICT\RefilterMe.txt"
    SET SPT2="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.ReFiltered.txt"
    SET SPT3="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp.txt"
    SET SPT4="C:\ICT\Refiltered"
    SET SPT8="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programs.txt"
    SET SPT6="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp2Test.txt"
    SET SPT5="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"
    SET SPT7="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Filtered.Temp.txt"

TYPE %SPT% > %SPT5%
TYPE %SPT% > %SPT8%
```

The more I tested the wierder it got. Removing SPT5 completely only gives "Cannot Open" without adding what it cannot open. It is so odd that I am lost for words or reasons why. It works fine if i change SPT5 from %CNAME% to RefilterMe but I would love to know why this wierd issue occures and maybe someone on this forum got an idea.

Edit: As requested by Compo.

A bigger portion of the code to better help you understand the issue.

```
@ECHO off
    set CNAME="RefilterMe"
    SET SPT="C:\ICT\RefilterMe.txt"
    SET SPT2="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.ReFiltered.txt"
    SET SPT3="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp.txt"
    SET SPT4="C:\ICT\Refiltered"
    SET "SPT5=C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"
    SET SPT6="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp2Test.txt"
    SET SPT7="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Filtered.Temp.txt"

TYPE %SPT% > %SPT5%
ECHO . > %SPT2%

ECHO Cleaning Collected Entries ...

ECHO Programms > %SPT7%


::First part with possible common programms

    (FindStr /IC:"Microsoft Edge" "%SPT5%" >Nul && (ECHO Edge))>> %SPT7%
    (FindStr /IC:"Mozilla Firefox" "%SPT5%" >Nul && (ECHO Firefox))>> %SPT7%
```

To add a bit more to confusion here is the variable setting from the original script I wrote which will contain the filtering part. With this there are no errors which is very wierd.

```
WMIC bios get serialnumber > C:\SN.txt
::Extracting only the serialnumber from the txt file
TYPE C:\SN.txt | findstr /v /c:"SerialNumber" > C:\SN1.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\SN1.txt) DO SET SN1=%%x
::Defining the variable for the Filename
SET "SN=%SN1: =%"
::Deleting the created Files
DEL C:\SN.txt
DEL C:\SN1.txt

::Defining Save Paths (SPT) and the Move Path (MPT) of the Tool
SET MPT="\\<IP Address>\<Path>\ICT"
SET SPT="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Complete.txt"
SET SPT2="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Filtered.txt"
SET SPT3="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Temp.txt"
SET SPT4="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Screen.txt"
SET SPT5="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Programs.txt"
SET SPT6="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Screen.Temp.txt"
SET SPT7="C:\%COMPUTERNAME%.%SN%.Filtered.Temp.txt"
```

Hopefully this makes things clearer.

Comment: My guess: PATH expansion. When the cmd CLI parse the `%SPT5%` path, it sees "Programms" that probably matches a directory in current path or in %PATH%. Thus it translates it to `"Programms[space]..."`, which indeed shallows the original double quotes. What's happen if you quote your variables like that:  `SET "CNAME=..." SET "SPT=..."` ?

Comment: You shouldn't quote the value with a `set` command. Use preferred syntax `set "var=value"` (note the position of the quotes). This saves against poison chars but doesn't include the quotes. Later, when using the variable, use quotes where appropriate: `SET "SPT5=C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"` (still no quotes in the value) and later `findstr "stringtofind" "%spt2%"`

Comment: I had one try where I renamed Programms to proper and it still did the same. Sorry for leaving this out.

Comment: Unless I'm half asleep, I'm struggling to determine how you're getting an error message from `findstr.exe`, when there is not a single command or line in your examples which use that utility. The idea of this site is that you submit sufficient information for us to reproduce your issue, and I've got to be honest, It boggles my mind to see an error message from a utility/command you're not using. Please clarify where that utility is used, and [edit] your question to include the [mcve]. From your two submitted examples, the only commands using the correct syntax, is the first line `@ECHO off`

Comment: @compo The error message comes from Findstr, that is correct, but I have added TYPE %SPT% > %SPT5% to create the file. I will add one line for the example.

Comment: Well @VarmintLP, I've asked you to post a [mcve], and you can click on that link to find out what it means. If you do not [edit] your question submitting an actual issue we can replicate, I'll vote to close your question!

Comment: For FINDSTR, the file to search is provided as an argument string, thus  there is no path expansion with it (the quotes will not be removed). Then FINDSTR looks _literaly_ for a filename corresponding to the string, and if the string include quote ("), as they're not removed, the `\ ` from the ICT path will be shallowed as `" `.  Anyway, FINDSTR will not find the file.. Change your `SET var="value"` with `SET "var=value"`, that will fix it. And @compo is right, you should provide _all_ the related commands, or you'll let us "guess".

Comment: @Compo Sorry for taking a bit longer.
@Z

Comment: @Zilog80 I wonder why it's working for the other 6 of the 7 variables.

Comment: As it will not fit in a comment, i'll add an answer with a simple example explaining wath's happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple batch from your use case illustrating why `FINDSTR` can't find the files which include `%CNAME` with your actual script:

```
@ECHO off
    set CNAME="RefilterMe"
    SET SPT="C:\ICT\RefilterMe.txt"
    SET SPT2="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.ReFiltered.txt"
    SET SPT3="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp.txt"
    SET SPT4="C:\ICT\Refiltered"
    SET SPT8="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programs.txt"
    SET SPT6="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Temp2Test.txt"
    SET SPT5="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"
    SET SPT7="C:\ICT\%CNAME%.Filtered.Temp.txt"

call echo "more < %SPT4%"
more < %SPT4%

call echo "more < %SPT3%"
more < %SPT3%

call echo "more < %SPT5%"
more < %SPT5%

call echo "more < %SPT8%"
more < %SPT8%

for %%i in (%SPT3%) do echo %%i
for %%i in (%SPT4%) do echo %%i
for %%i in (%SPT5%) do echo %%i
for %%i in (%SPT8%) do echo %%i

call echo "FINDSTR x %SPT3%"
FINDSTR x %SPT3%
call echo "FINDSTR x %SPT4%"
FINDSTR x %SPT4%
call echo "FINDSTR x %SPT5%"
FINDSTR x %SPT5%
call echo "FINDSTR x %SPT8%"
FINDSTR x %SPT8%
```

Its output with files having *'aax'*, *'bxb'*, 'xee'_, *'xff'* as content :

```
"more < "C:\ICT\Refiltered""
"xee"
"more < "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Temp.txt""
"xff"
"more < "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programms.txt""
"aax"
"more < "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programs.txt""
"bxb"
"C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Temp.txt"
"C:\ICT\Refiltered"
"C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programms.txt"
"C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programs.txt"
"FINDSTR x "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Temp.txt""
FINDSTR : Can't open  C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Temp.txt
"FINDSTR x "C:\ICT\Refiltered""
"xee"
"FINDSTR x "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programms.txt""
FINDSTR : Can't open  C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Programms.txt
"FINDSTR x "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Programs.txt""
FINDSTR : Can't open C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Programs.txt
```

As you can see for `%SPT3%`, the FINDSTR command will be `FINDSTR x "C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Temp.txt"`. As it is not a path in a redirection ( `< "path"` ), their is no quotes removal. `FINDSTR` will then try to find the file `"C:\ICT\"RefilterMe".Temp.txt"` as is, the quotes are then trimed but as there is an escaped quote (`\"` from `C:\ICT\"`), this quote is kept as is. Thus, FINDSTR will look for `C:\ICT"RefilterMe.Temp.txt`. And indeed can't find it.

If you change `set CNAME="RefilterMe"` with `set "CNAME=RefilterMe"`, you 'll see that the script will behave as expected for the `FINDSTR` commands.

I'll suggest you to avoid quotes in `cmd batch` variable values as most as possible when they are not a significant part of the value. You should fix all your `SET` this way.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Thank you very much. Also for the explanation. I did not fully understand it, but you are right. I should set my variables like this from now on: >set "CNAME=RefilterMe"<
I love avoiding such issues it's just always a matter of how to find the things I should avoid that I didn't know about.

Comment: Found one case where "x=something" doesn't work.  In the main script I have this.
SET "MPT=\\<IP-Address>\Example (Example)\ICT"
MOVE %SPT% %MPT%
MOVE %SPT2% %MPT%
MOVE %SPT4% %MPT%
Error:
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
When I do it the other way with Set var="something" it works as intended. I tried and it is due to the space in the path. But that space sadly has to stay. :/
Got any tips with that?

Comment: Keep `SET "MPT=\\IP\Example (Example)"` and double quote your _use_ of the variable with `MOVE` :  `MOVE "%SPT%" "%MPT%"` etc. Here, the quotes will be meaningful for the `MOVE` command, it will take the unquoted value, space included, at full.